# How can I create a loop inside a method so that when we reach the end of the array or beyond, it breaks and returns a sum?

Tags: python, methods

I am solving the following problem: we are given an array of positive integers, and want to return the maximum sum of non adjacent elements in the array.

e.g. `array = [75,105,120,75,90,135]`

Then **max would be 330**, attained by **summing 75,120 and 135**.

My idea is simply to write two methods, the first takes the index of the current maximum, then evaluates the 2nd and 3rd element after it (skipping the adjacent element), and returns the larger of the two.

The second method starts with identifying the larger of `array[0]` and `array[1]`; then it will pass the index of whichever is larger to the first method.

The challenge I am having is I don't know how to write code to loop in the second method, so that we traverse the whole array and break when we reach the end of the array. Any ideas how I can add a line or two of code to achieve this?

Here is my solution:

```py
def nextMaximum(indexOfCurrentMax): 
    return max(array[indexOfCurrentMax+2],array[indexOfCurrentMax+3])

def maxSubsetSumNoAdjacent(array):
    total = 0 
    indexOfCurrentMax = array.index(max(array[0],array[1]))
    total += array[indexOfCurrentMax]
    
    currentMax = nextMaximum(indexOfCurrentMax)
```

Comment: `while indexOfCurrentMax < len(array) - 3:`? (since your function goes up to `indexOfCurrentMax + 3)

Comment: Have you already found the solution by your own? In this case you can add an answer to your own question.

Comment: Alvin the above code is my solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a [*generator function*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) which returns all possible combinations of non-adjacent elements and use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) passing [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) as *`key` argument* to find a combination with maximum sum:

```py
def get_non_adjacent(src, start_index=0):
    for i in range(start_index, len(src)):
        yield src[i],
        for el in get_non_adjacent(src, i + 2):
            yield src[i], *el

array = [75, 105, 120, 75, 90, 135]
max_combination = max(get_non_adjacent(array), key=sum)
```

Comment: Thanks Olvin, one question what does the * do? in line 5, you have *el

Comment: @user15877202, it [unpacks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) result of recursive `get_non_adjacent()` call *(which is tuple)* into result of current call. Basically it makes result in single yield flat. You can compare `list(get_non_adjacent(array))` with `*` and without to see the difference.